# IF formula errors on my excel free version

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I don´t understand why this is happening. I´m using a free online excel

```
=IF(F38>=4,5,"Excellent",IF(F38>=3,5,"Very Good",IF(F38>=2,5,"Good",IF(F38>=1,5,"in Progress","Not Satisfactory"))))
```

What am I doing wrong?

No matter what I do, the error remains

Comment: Your decimal separator the `,` is interpreted as the formula separator `,`.

Comment: Thank you so much! In fact, the error disappeared, but the return value is incorrect. As I wa waiting for help, i tried with the IFS formula:

Comment: =IFs(F38=1,"Not Satisfactory",F38>=1.5,"In Progress",F38>=2.5,"Good",F38>=3.5,"Very Good",F38>=4.5,"Excellent")

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel goes through the formula from the first condition to the last condition so if you have a number that's `4.3`, you'll get "In Progress" because `4.3` is greater than or equal to `1.5`

What you'll want to do is put the "Excellent" condition first so:

```
=IFS(F38>=4.5, "Excellent", F38>=3.5,"Very Good", F38>=2.5, "Good", F38>=1.5, "In Progress",F38<=1,"Not Satisfactory")
```

Do note the last condition `F38<=1` is there if you have a result that's less than or equal to 1